# Taming Visual Studio Code IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Suppose I'm writing a typescript expression, and realize the local variable I need doesn't exist yet. No problem, I think, let's simply finish typing the line before moving the cursor to type the variable declaration:

```
production: level.Sunlifter * 2 * perYear,
```

Alas, typing that final comma triggers IntelliSense, which helpfully changes my code to

```
production: level.Sunlifter * 2 * prepareSyntheticListenerName,
```

and imports

```
import { prepareSyntheticListenerName } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/util';
```

Apparently, IntelliSense has realized that the characters of "perYear" appear in "**p**r**e**pa**r**eS**y**ntheticListen**er**N**a**me" in nearly the same order ...

Can I somehow tell Visual Studio Code to be less permissive when matching imported identifiers?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing `esc` before typing the comma is the only way I know of.

A workaround that may help is to configure VSCode to only import from certain packages. Then at least there's then less possible mistakes for it to make.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "types" : ["node", "lodash", "express"]
   }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, similar issue here. Escape is the only key that can maybe bypass those IntelliSense options.